# Java .JAR to desktop shortcuts/proper apps for windows, mac and debian

Tags: java, jar, desktop-application, executable-jar, shortcut-file

I have a multiplatform jar, that can run when clicked on all 3 platforms.

What would be the best way to install desktop shortcuts / apps, that would basically just symlink or link to that jar?

Answer (score 0):

I think you require some sort of wizard installer. Which will take care of putting your jar to specific directory (program directory) and create desktop shortcut.
For windows OS you can use [Jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thats just for windows. I need one for all three.